# I can't wrap a command inside watch

Tags: bash, watch

I have this perfectly working command:

```
netstat -tuplean | awk '{NR>1; if( $6 ~ /ESTABLISHED/ ) print "\033[0;31m" $5  "   \033[01;31m"$6;if ($6 ~ /_WAIT/ ) print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6}'
```

I cannot wrap it into a watch command. Here is what I tried:

1. escape all single quotes (`'`)

   ```
   watch 'netstat -tuplean | awk '\''{NR>1; if( $6 ~ /ESTABLISHED/ ) print "\033[0;31m" $5  "   \033[01;31m"$6
     if ($6 ~ /_WAIT/ ) print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6}'\'''
   ```

   output:

   ```
   ^[0;31m34.210.39.83:443   ^[01;31mESTABLISHED
   ^[0;31m34.107.221.82:80   ^[01;31mESTABLISHED
   ^[0;31m34.107.221.82:80   ^[01;31mESTABLISHED
   ^[0;34m34.117.59.81:80   ^[01;32mTIME_WAIT
   ^[0;34m34.117.59.81:80   ^[01;32mTIME_WAIT
   ^[0;31m192.168.0.1:67   ^[01;31mESTABLISHED
   ```
2. escape both single and double quotes (`'` and `"`)

   ```
   watch 'netstat -tuplean | awk '\''{NR>1; if( $6 ~ /ESTABLISHED/ ) print '\'"\033[0;31m'\'" $5  "   \033[01;31m'\'"$6
     if ($6 ~ /_WAIT/ ) print '\'"\033[0;34m'\'"$5  '\'"   \033[01;32m'\'"$6}'\'''
   ```

   output:

   ```
    bash: syntax error near unexpected token `print'
   ```
3. export the command and then call it back this way:

   ```
    while : do ...<cmd>...; sleep 2;done
    watch -n 3 -x bash -c "$cmd"
   ```

   it does not work neither because the same problem occurs when defining the variable.
4. I tried to make a script using `while : do ...<cmd>...; sleep 2;done`

   it does not work because it looks like the sleep delay is not taken into account; as a result, the output comes out too fast -- there is no way to read something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command where you enclosed everything in single-quotes and properly escaped the old single-quotes is almost good. It prints "garbage" because you didn't use `watch --color`. Run this:

```
watch --color 'netstat -tuplean | awk '\''{NR>1; if( $6 ~ /ESTABLISHED/ ) print "\033[0;31m" $5  "   \033[01;31m"$6
  if ($6 ~ /_WAIT/ ) print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6
  if ($6 ~ /TIME_WAIT/ ) print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6}'\'
```

<sup>(Note the final `''` in your original code is a single-quoted empty string concatenated with what's before. It changes nothing. My code omitted this useless `''` completely.)</sup>

From [`man 1 watch`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html):

> `-c`, `--color`
> Interpret ANSI color and style sequences.

Comment: .@Kamil: good point to you. Regarding the final  ( ' ' ), I try to keep the logic: ( ' \ ' ' ) corresponding to the end of awk snippet and one last ( ' ) corresponding to close the watch command.

Answer (score 4):

You did not share the complete code you used in your loop-based attempts, so here are a few options you have to avoid handling multiple levels of quoting, freely based on a slightly modified AWK script.

You may save your code as an executable file:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

netstat -tuplean | awk '
  $6 ~ /ESTABLISHED/ { print "\033[0;31m" $5  "   \033[01;31m"$6 }
  $6 ~ /_WAIT/ { print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6 }
  $6 ~ /TIME_WAIT/ { print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6 }
  END { printf("%s","\033(B\033[m") }      # Turn fancy formatting off'
```

and make `watch` run it, noting that, as pointed out in [the answer you already have](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/664520/315749), you also need the `--color` option:

```bsh
watch -n 3 --color ./my_script
```

Alternatively, you may use an infinite loop — I am unable to guess why, in your case, "the sleep delay is not taken into account"; this seems to work as expected:

```bsh
while :
do
  clear
  netstat -tuplean | awk '
    $6 ~ /ESTABLISHED/ { print "\033[0;31m" $5  "   \033[01;31m"$6 }
    $6 ~ /_WAIT/ { print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6 }
    $6 ~ /TIME_WAIT/ { print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6 }
    END { printf("%s","\033(B\033[m") }     # Turn fancy formatting off'
  sleep 3
done
```

To save your script in a variable and run it as `bash -c "$cmd"`, you may combine command substitution and a here-document. If the label of a here-document is quoted (here, `'EOT'`), its content is not expanded:

```bsh
cmd=$(cat <<'EOT'
netstat -tuplean | awk '
  $6 ~ /ESTABLISHED/ { print "\033[0;31m" $5  "   \033[01;31m"$6 }
  $6 ~ /_WAIT/ { print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6 }
  $6 ~ /TIME_WAIT/ { print "\033[0;34m"$5  "   \033[01;32m"$6 }
  END { printf("%s","\033(B\033[m") }      # Turn fancy formatting off'
EOT
)
```

Comment: +1. writing this as a stand-alone script is a good way to avoid quoting issues due to the conflicting quoting requirements of `watch` and shell and the `awk` script.

Comment: What is `\033(B` escape code for? I've asked here [What is the meaning of ESC ( B ANSI escape code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/722244/1806)

Comment: @jcubic Honestly, I wouldn't know. Most likely I took that sequence from the output of `tput`, using a terminal emulator where `TERM` was set to `xterm`, without much thought on the meaning of every single character.