# What is the meaning of ESC ( B ANSI escape code?

Tags: bash, escape-characters, ansi

I'm working on the ANSI escape codes interpreter and I have this escape code from the `top` command.

```
[K
[7m    PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU  %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND                                      (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m  23805 kuba      20   0   41,1g 247308  70936 S  22,2   1,5  22:40.52 slack                                        (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m[1m 213109 kuba      20   0  226580   4244   3352 R  16,7   0,0   0:00.06 top                                          (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m   1541 root      20   0 2636312 102624  47028 S  11,1   0,6 407:36.60 Xorg                                         (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m   8465 kuba      20   0  849744  46016  27724 S  11,1   0,3 171:40.22 pavucontrol                                  (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m   2084 kuba      20   0 1426852  74796  51248 S   5,6   0,5 182:40.85 xfwm4                                        (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m  86899 kuba      20   0 1129,7g 525864 132432 S   5,6   3,3 119:14.01 chrome                                       (B[m[39;49m[K
(B[m      1 root      20   0  173284  16232   9628 S   0,0   0,1   0:22.51 systemd                                      (B[m[39;49m[K
```

I was searching this document [XTerm Control Sequences](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Controls-beginning-with-ESC) and found that it's USASCII character encoding. But why it's only the output of a top command and why it's on every single line?

Can this escape code be ignored when parsing and displaying on the web? Or is it something different and used for a different purpose?

I've also found this document [Line Draw Characters without VGA Fonts](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x622.html) but here (B is used as the ending of line drawing, in my case, it's used for a different purpose

Comment: Relating, on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/q/36279015/10488700

Comment: @fra-san thanks so it seems that this is exactly what the XTerm document has and can be ignored.